# monitor network status for systemd script

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, systemd

I am writing a service script under `systemd` which logs bandwidth usage every 1 hour. If the network goes down, *something* should tell this script that network is down and the script will stop temporarily. Similarly, if network is up again, *it* should tell it that network is up.

I am using bash to write script on Ubuntu 15.10

Please before you suggest a solution, please note I don't need a work around for this, like pinging some server.

Comment: Have you looked at [`NetworkManager(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/NetworkManager.8.html)? It describes the interface to a bunch of `run-parts` scripts in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` for just this type of purpose.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a minimal example of what your script should do when the network is down and what it should do when it's up. What command do you use to get bandwidth usage? Also tell us more details like i) how is the script being run exactly? ii) do you want to check whether the network is down or whether there is no internet access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is use the event-driven statuses already available in the Network Manager.

1. Create a file `NetStatus.x` in `/etc`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/NetStatus.up
   ```
2. Add the following text:

   > This is the NetStatus file.  If its name has an extension of "up", it means the network status is up, whereas an extension of "down" means its down. (Duh!)
3. Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown` and add the bold statements below:

   ```
   case "$2" in
       up|vpn-up)
           export MODE="start"
           export PHASE="post-up"
           exec run-parts /etc/network/if-up.d
           mv /etc/NetStatus.down /etc/NetStatus.up
           ;;
       down|vpn-down)
           export MODE="stop"
           export PHASE="post-down"
           exec run-parts /etc/network/if-post-down.d
           mv /etc/NetStatus.up /etc/NetStatus.down
           ;;
   ```
4. Modify your own collection script to check for the existence of `/etc/NetStatus.up` prior to actually start collecting data by the following code snippet:

   ```
   if [ -e /etc/NetStatus.up ] ; then
     #move your existing collection in here
   fi
   ```

### Why?

A rename is the fastest way of changing a status on any OS, including floppy-based systems and is extremely easy to use.  I've used the above system to have server statuses, backup statuses, calculation statuses from lowly MS-DOS based systems up to super computers.

Comment: event driven is what I wanted at first place, my restriction was on polling, which is what you suggested first. Event driven is the idea of David Foerster in comment